# ArcSDESQLExecute to query and update from multiple SDE Databases

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, sql

I am trying to use ArcSDESQLExecute to return the results of a join and then write the return query into a Feature Class located in a different database. Using Microsoft SQL Server and Arc10.2.2

Is there any way to use ArcSDESQLExecute to UPDATE a table located in one SDE database from the query results of tables/feature classes from another SDE_database? Would using a linked server work? Or is ArcSDESQLExecute limited to manipulating tables within the same database?

Comment: Please provide the SQL that you would want to execute, with an indication of how it's going to cross databases.

Comment: For this operation I would use an arcpy join... that is I think you're trying to join two SDE tables and output to a SDE Personal, different SDE database or file/personal geodatabase (the output is a feature class so it *has* to be a spatial database).